# Which ssh starup script is invoked by ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, upstart, init.d

I am trying to run two sshd processes, one for admin and one for sftp. Ubuntu 14.04 on digital ocean has both upstart in '/etc/init/ssh' and init.d in '/etc/init.d/ssh`.

Is this just digitalocean or all 14.04?

Which one launches sshd? And which isn't being used / can i delete?

So far I've read each file and The files do not reference each other.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out.

```
find /etc/rc* | grep ssh
```

Seeing that there is no link to the `/etc/init.d/ssh` file is a clear indication the service isn't started from there.

Just to be safe I threw an `echo "foobar" >> initd.txt` into the /etc/init.d/ssh file and an `echo "foobar" >> /root/upstart.txt` into the `/etc/init/ssh.conf` file. `reboot` and found the `upstart.txt` in the `/root` directory.

So the answer is the job isn't started unless rc launches it.